# sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex5.sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

What does this mean? I am attempting to go through Zed Shaw's alpha of Learn SQL The Hard Way, and I'm confused about the process of creating db and sql files, and specifically what the "<" means in this context.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is shell or command line syntax.

The `<` means "redirect standard input".  It means use `ex5.sql` as an input file.  It's an operator that your command line interpreter understands (`bash` on Linux, `cmd.exe` or Command Prompt on Windows, Terminal on OS X).  `-echo` means print the commands executed to the screen as they're run.  `ex3.db` is the file name of the resulting database.

The command tells sqlite to create or open a database called `ex3.db`, then run the SQL commands in `ex5.sql` with that database.  Additionally, print all the commands as they're run to the screen.

You can see the full command line syntax by running `sqlite3 -help`.